# GitHub Actions returns An HTTP protocol error occurred: statusCode = 400 on posting slack notification

Tags: github-actions, slack

I have been using `sonots/slack-notice-action@v3` for posting slack notification with github actions workflow. But recently while posting the notification the workflow shows **`An HTTP protocol error occurred: statusCode = 400`**.[image]

I could not find anything useful online so posted here. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate a new webhook for slack channel. The older one is expired. I stumbled upon a same issue few months ago.